# Com exportar string HTML para PDF Compactada (zip)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, arquivo-zip

Tenho essa string: 
`<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><body><FORM method="post"><table><tr><td>Nome:</td><td>JOÃO DA SILVA</td></tr><tr><td>NOME:</td><td>MARCOS ALVES</td></tr></table></BODY></HTML>` 
 salva em uma **tabela** e preciso através do click do botão **exportar para pdf de forma já *compactada (.zip)***, usando alguma **api free**. É possível ?

Implementei a **ótima resposta do George Wurthmann** abaixo, mas conforme comentado o projeto disponível no GitHub como exemplo gera o PDF exibindo as tags HTML, acredito que seja algum detalhe no código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui adaptei o código conforme minhas necessidades, alterando a string contendo table HTML fixo no código para um retorno de uma tabela do banco de dados:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetPdfFileZiped(ProcessamentoRegistros pProcessamentoRegistros)
        {
            pProcessamentoRegistros.IdProcessamentoDiario = 1;
            pProcessamentoRegistros.IdRegistro = 1;
            pProcessamentoRegistros.IdServico = 2;
            ProcessamentoRegistros _processamento = _IRepositorio.ObterProcessamentoRegistros(pProcessamentoRegistros);

            var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            var minhaStringHTML = _processamento.DocumentoHtml;    // @"<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><body><FORM method='post'><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></BODY></HTML>";

            doc.Open();
            Paragraph paragrafo = new Paragraph(minhaStringHTML, new Font(Font.NORMAL, 12));
            paragrafo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            doc.Add(paragrafo);
            doc.Close();

            using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //Cria um arquivo ZIP
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
                {
                    //Criar a entrada do PDF para o arquivo ZIP
                    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("MeuPDFZipado.pdf");

                    //Pegando o stream do PDF em memória
                    using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()))
                    {
                        using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                        {
                            //Copia o stream do PDF para o ZIP
                            originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
            }
        }
```

**Essa é table HTML:**

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0">
<script language=javascript>
//function MudarPagina() {
//  window.history.back();
//}
</script>
</HEAD>
<!--body bgcolor=white onBlur=MudarPagina();-->
<body bgcolor=white>
    <FORM method="post" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: white">
    <!--FORM name="Imprimir" method="post" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: white"-->
<br>    
<table>
<tr>
<td align=center><a href="javascript:window.print();"><IMG src="https://www.sifge.caixa.gov.br/Empresa/Crf/images/botimprimir.gif" border=0></a>
<a href="javascript:window.history.back();"><IMG src="https://www.sifge.caixa.gov.br/Empresa/Crf/images/botvoltar.gif" border=0></a></td>
</tr>

<tr><td>

<table width="75%" CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=10 border=1 align=center bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#CCCCCC">


<tr>
<td>    

    <TABLE WIDTH=100% BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 style="color: black" class=txtcentral>
        <tr>
            <td align=left><IMG border="0" src="https://www.sifge.caixa.gov.br/Empresa/Crf/images/caixa.gif" width=180 height=44></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td align=rigth><span style="font-size: 13pt" align=center><strong>Certificado de Regularidade do FGTS - CRF</strong></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <TABLE WIDTH=100% BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 style="color: black" class=txtcentral>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <TD width=22%><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Inscrição:</strong></font></TD>
            <TD ><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:8pt">08439659/0001-50</font></TD>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=22% valign=top nowrap><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Razão Social:</strong></font></TD>
            <td><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:8pt">CPFL ENERGIAS RENOVAVEIS S A</font></TD>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width=22% nowrap><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Nome Fantasia:</strong></font></TD>
            <td ><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:8pt">CPFL RENOVAVEIS</font></TD>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width=22% valign=top><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Endereço:</strong></font></TD>
            <td ><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:8pt">AV DOUTOR CARDOSO DE MELO   1184   ANDAR 7 / VILA OLIMPIA / SAO PAULO / SP / 4548-004</font></TD>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <TD colspan=2 style="text-align: justify"><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt">A Caixa Econômica Federal, no uso da atribuição que lhe confere o Art. 7, da
            Lei 8.036, de 11 de maio de 1990, certifica que, nesta data, a empresa acima identificada
            encontra-se em situação regular perante o Fundo de Garantia do Tempo de Serviço - FGTS.
            </font>
            </TD>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: justify" colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt">O presente Certificado não servirá de prova contra cobrança de quaisquer débitos referentes
            a contribuições e/ou encargos devidos, decorrentes das obrigações com o FGTS.</font>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Validade: </strong>28/02/2017 a 29/03/2017</font></TD>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Certificação Número: </strong>2017022805233090232330</font></TD></TR>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <TD colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt">Informação obtida em 15/03/2017, às 17:14:51.</font></TD>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <TD style="text-align: justify" colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt">A utilização deste Certificado
                para os fins previstos em Lei está condicionada à verificação de
                autenticidade no site da Caixa: <strong>www.caixa.gov.br</strong></font></TD>
            </tr>
    </TABLE>
</form>

</td></tr></table>

</td>
</tr>

</table> 

<script language=javascript>
//window.print();
</script>   
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Coloquei o link disso funcionando no GitHub.

Comment: @George Wurthmann baixei o projeto do GitHub e o pdf gerado mostra as tags html pro usuário e isso não faz sentido eu vou editar a pergunta e adicionar o print do pdf.

Comment: Acabei de ver sua edição. No `_processamento.DocumentoHtml` tem toda sua string `HTML`?

Comment: Editei a resposta e atualizei o projeto no Git com oque você precisa. Editei a pegunta pois sua string HTML faltava fechar o `<FORM>` e isso ocasionava erro ao tentar converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **PDF** você pode gerar com o **iTextSharp**, é bem simples.

O **Zip** pode ser gerado de forma nativa pelo `C#` com o [`System.IO.Compression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx).

Portanto vai precisar referênciar:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
```

Veja neste exemplo como usar:

```
namespace Exemplo_PDF_e_ZIP.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetPdfFile()
        {
            var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            var minhaStringHTML = @"<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><body><FORM method='post'><table><tr><td>Nome:</td><td>JOÃO DA SILVA</td></tr><tr><td>NOME:</td><td>MARCOS ALVES</td></tr></table></FORM></BODY></HTML>";

            doc.Open();
            using (var srHtml = new StringReader(minhaStringHTML))
            {
                //Convertendo o HTML
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pw, doc, srHtml);
            }
            doc.Close();

            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "result.pdf");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetPdfFileZiped()
        {
            var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            var minhaStringHTML = @"<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><body><FORM method='post'><table><tr><td>Nome:</td><td>JOÃO DA SILVA</td></tr><tr><td>NOME:</td><td>MARCOS ALVES</td></tr></table></FORM></BODY></HTML>";

            doc.Open();
            using (var srHtml = new StringReader(minhaStringHTML))
            {
                //Convertendo o HTML
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pw, doc, srHtml);
            }
            doc.Close();

            using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //Cria um arquivo ZIP
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
                {
                    //Criar a entrada do PDF para o arquivo ZIP
                    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("MeuPDFZipado.pdf");

                    //Pegando o stream do PDF em memória
                    using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()))
                    {
                        using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                        {
                            //Copia o stream do PDF para o ZIP
                            originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Após as edições na pergunta, você informou que não quer imprimir as tags e sim o conteúdo do `HTML`. Para isso usei o [`XMLWorker`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/) do `iTextSharp`.

Você precisará instala-lo também:

> PM> Install-Package itextsharp.xmlworker

Além dos `namespaces` que informei acima use também:

```
using iTextSharp.tool.xml;
```

[Coloquei o projeto no Github](https://github.com/Wurthma/Exemplo_PDF_ZIP). Assim poderá baixar pra usar de exemplo e ver funcionando.

Comment: Olá @George Wurthmann muito boa sua reposta, bem didático, porém o o PDF exibe exatamente uma **String**, o que quero é exibir os dados que virão nesse Html, vou editar a pergunta para explicar mellhor.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV, você quer exportar a tabela, é isso? Do jeito que está no `HTML` ficar no `PDF`? Se for isso é necessário mais detalhes, pois não sei como está sendo gerado seu `HTML`, imagino que através de uma `View` já que está usando `MVC`, então é necessário você postar detalhes dela também.

Comment: Eu não quero exibir as tags HTML, somente o conteúdo, exemplo:  **Nome: MARCOS SILVA** eu editei a pergunta e adicinei um print do pdf gerado.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV, eu entendi oque quer dizer, mas, conforme expliquei antes, preciso saber como está sendo gerado sua table. No meu código eu coloquei a string em uma variável manualmente, pois da a entender na sua pergunta que você já tem a string que quer imprimir.

Comment: está resolvido conforme os comentários anteriores postados no Post da pergunta, porém depois de todo o trabalho que tive vejo que o iTextSharp não gera no pdf os styles ? Correto ?

Comment: @AdrianoSUV, CSS? Não está incluso já que não tinha nada na tag que colocou de exemplo, mas é possível com o XMLWorker. Pesquise sobre [iTextSharp CSSResolverPipeline](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html).

Comment: Correto @George Wurthmann, não havia comentado sobre o CSS vou pesquisar sobre.

Comment: Não sei se é o caso de abrir um outro post, tentei gerar vários arquivos `zip` dentro de um `foreach` sem sucesso devido o  `return new FileContentResult`, tem como **gerar mais de um arquivo `zip`** dentro de um `foreach` ?

Comment: @AdrianoSUV, no return da ActionResult só um pode ser retornado. Se você quer retornar vários PDF, por que não gerá os PDFs no foreach e depois Zipa eles em um único arquivo? Não faz sentido gerar vários zips, gera apenas 1 e dentro dele poem todos arquivos que precisa.

Comment: estou a fazer isso e to apanhando muito kkkk, implementei a a geração dentro de um foreach mas sempre retorna o último pdf, ou seja não consigo fazer o incremento dos arquivos rs

Comment: @AdrianoSUV, se não conseguir pode abrir uma questão com sua dúvida que eu ou alguma outra pessoa tenta te ajudar.