# Erro ao converter HTML para PDF usando XMLWorkerHelper

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, itextsharp

Durante a exportação do arquivo HTML para PDF usando [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) e [XMLWorker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html) ocorre erro em algumas situações dizendo que determinada tag não está fechada e pesquisando encontrei esse post [How to convert HTML to valid XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092532/how-to-convert-html-to-valid-xhtml) (mas é em javascript) que a conversão deve ser em m formato XHTML pois é certeza de que as tags estão corretamente formatadas.

Minha aplicação consulta uma tabela SQL de onde retorna formularios HTML salvos e quando eu tento transforma-las em PDF ocorre erro dizendo que determinada tag não está fechada, abaixo é o código que uso para exportar para PDF:

```
public ActionResult GetPdfFileZiped(ProcessamentoRegistros pProcessamentoRegistros)
        {
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pw, doc, srHtml);

ocorre erro pois a estrutura do HTML eventualmente não está bem formatada
pProcessamentoRegistros.IdProcessamentoDiario = 1;
                pProcessamentoRegistros.IdRegistro = 1;
                pProcessamentoRegistros.IdServico = 2;
                ProcessamentoRegistros _processamento = _IRepositorio.ObterProcessamentoRegistros(pProcessamentoRegistros);

                var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                var pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
                var minhaStringHTML = @_processamento.DocumentoHtml.Trim();

                doc.Open();

                using (var srHtml = new StringReader(minhaStringHTML))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pw, doc, srHtml); // <-- AQUI OCORRE ERRO
                }
                doc.Close();

                using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
                    {
                        var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("MeuPDFZipado.pdf");                        
                        using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()))
                        {
                            using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                            {
                                originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
                }
}
```

---

Por exempo, abaixo a tag img não está fechada e eu não tenho controle na sua formatação, o erro ocorre em algumas outras tags:

```
<IMG border="0" src="https://www.sifge.caixa.gov.br/Empresa/Crf/images/caixa.gif" width=180 height=44>
```

---

Abaixo é o HTML completo::

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0">
<script language=javascript>
//function MudarPagina() {
//  window.history.back();
//}
</script>
</HEAD>
<!--body bgcolor=white onBlur=MudarPagina();-->
<body bgcolor=white>
    <FORM method="post" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: white">
    <!--FORM name="Imprimir" method="post" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: white"-->
<br>    
<table>
<tr>
<td align=center><a href="javascript:window.print();"><IMG src="https://www.sifge.caixa.gov.br/Empresa/Crf/images/botimprimir.gif" border=0></a>
<a href="javascript:window.history.back();"><IMG src="https://www.sifge.caixa.gov.br/Empresa/Crf/images/botvoltar.gif" border=0></a></td>
</tr>

<tr><td>

<table width="75%" CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=10 border=1 align=center bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#CCCCCC">


<tr>
<td>    

    <TABLE WIDTH=100% BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 style="color: black" class=txtcentral>
        <tr>
            <td align=left><IMG border="0" src="https://www.sifge.caixa.gov.br/Empresa/Crf/images/caixa.gif" width=180 height=44></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td align=rigth><span style="font-size: 13pt" align=center><strong>Certificado de Regularidade do FGTS - CRF</strong></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <TABLE WIDTH=100% BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 style="color: black" class=txtcentral>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <TD width=22%><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Inscrição:</strong></font></TD>
            <TD ><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:8pt">08439659/0001-50</font></TD>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=22% valign=top nowrap><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Razão Social:</strong></font></TD>
            <td><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:8pt">CPFL ENERGIAS RENOVAVEIS S A</font></TD>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width=22% nowrap><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Nome Fantasia:</strong></font></TD>
            <td ><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:8pt">CPFL RENOVAVEIS</font></TD>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width=22% valign=top><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Endereço:</strong></font></TD>
            <td ><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:8pt">AV DOUTOR CARDOSO DE MELO   1184   ANDAR 7 / VILA OLIMPIA / SAO PAULO / SP / 4548-004</font></TD>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <TD colspan=2 style="text-align: justify"><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt">A Caixa Econômica Federal, no uso da atribuição que lhe confere o Art. 7, da
            Lei 8.036, de 11 de maio de 1990, certifica que, nesta data, a empresa acima identificada
            encontra-se em situação regular perante o Fundo de Garantia do Tempo de Serviço - FGTS.
            </font>
            </TD>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: justify" colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt">O presente Certificado não servirá de prova contra cobrança de quaisquer débitos referentes
            a contribuições e/ou encargos devidos, decorrentes das obrigações com o FGTS.</font>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Validade: </strong>28/02/2017 a 29/03/2017</font></TD>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt"><strong>Certificação Número: </strong>2017022805233090232330</font></TD></TR>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <TD colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt">Informação obtida em 15/03/2017, às 17:14:51.</font></TD>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <TD style="text-align: justify" colspan=2><font style=" font-family: Verdana;font-size:10pt">A utilização deste Certificado
                para os fins previstos em Lei está condicionada à verificação de
                autenticidade no site da Caixa: <strong>www.caixa.gov.br</strong></font></TD>
            </tr>
    </TABLE>
</form>

</td></tr></table>

</td>
</tr>

</table> 

<script language=javascript>
//window.print();
</script>   
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Como posso contornar esse problema ? Tem como fazer um parse no HTML e transformar em XHTML ?
Tem alguma outra alternativa **free** para converter esse HTML para PDF juntamente com os styles das tags ?

Comment: Apenas para questão de informação, segue link da sua [outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208080/com-exportar-string-html-para-pdf-compactada-zip) que fez com que chegasse a esse novo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como posso contornar esse problema ?

A forma correta de contornar seu problema é atacar a raiz dele. Ou seja, você deve corrigir seus `HTML`s para que a ferramenta possa trabalhar corretamente.
Algo que pode ser usado, por exemplo, é o [Validador do W3C](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html) para checar se o `HTML` passado possui erros.

> Tem como fazer um parse no HTML e transformar em XHTML ?

Não tenho experiência com a ferramenta, mas teste a [TidyManaged](https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged).

Abaixo um exemplo do seu uso:

```
using System;
using TidyManaged;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    using (Document doc = Document.FromString("<hTml><title>test</tootle><body>asd</body>"))
    {
      doc.ShowWarnings = false;
      doc.Quiet = true;
      doc.OutputXhtml = true;
      doc.CleanAndRepair();
      string parsed = doc.Save();
      Console.WriteLine(parsed);
    }
  }
}
```

A saida do `HTML` será algo assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Mac OS X (vers 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 13), see www.w3.org" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
asd
</body>
</html>
```

Provavelmente é possível fazer algo assim também com o [**API do W3C**](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html).

> Tem alguma outra alternativa free para converter esse HTML para PDF
>   juntamente com os styles das tags ?

O problema não é a geração do PDF e sim o HTML (problema raiz, conforme informei antes). Mas se algo te impede de fazer a correção no HTML, você pode tentar usar alguma ferramenta como a que indiquei acima para tentar dar um parse no seu HTML corrigindo os erros encontrados. Mas isso **não é 100% confiável**, alguns erros podem não ser detectados.

Comment: suas soluções foram muito boas, mas não tenho como eliminar o problema raiz na atual situação, porém contornei o problema raiz usando essa dll Pechkin: [https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin], daqui em diante pretendo fazer algumas melhorias na compactação do arquivo zip e para isso vou abrir um outro post.

Comment: Interessante essa [Peckin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin), obrigado por compartilhar o conteúdo.