# Exibir um mensagem de aguarde enquanto faz download de arquivo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, streaming, arquivo-zip

Como exibir a mensagem de aguarde durante a geração e compactação dos arquivos para dowload ?

Estou fazendo a geração, compacatação e [Gerar mais de um PDF em memória e exporta-lo em um arquivo compactado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208944/gerar-mais-de-um-pdf-em-mem%C3%B3ria-e-exporta-lo-em-um-arquivo-compactado)  respondido por [George Wurthmann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/35358/george-wurthmann)

Answer (score 0):

Essa foi minha solução: [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page) a implementação foi fácil conforme consta no site.